# How to highlight an inline code snippet in latex?

Tags: latex, markdown, overleaf

I would like to hightlight a piece of code in the middle of a body of text. I would like it to appear similar to the inline heightlight in markdown.

I want it to look like this: `tensorflow.keras.optimizers`

Comment: have a look at the `listings` package

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36404 can answer your question. An improved version to accommodate long words can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `listing` and `tcolorbox` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{foo}{
  listing only,
  nobeforeafter,
  after={\xspace},
  hbox,
  tcbox raise base,
  fontupper=\ttfamily,
  colback=lightgray,
  colframe=lightgray,
  size=fbox
  }

\begin{document}

text
\begin{foo}
code
\end{foo}
text


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use this two packages (minted, xcolor) as shown in the example below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{code_gray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

\begin{document}

This is an \colorbox{code_gray}{\mintinline{HTML}{<a>}} HTML tag.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will blow up spectacularly if you use fragile content nested in the argument of another macro. Just a silly example: try `#` and see what happens :)

Comment: minted has build in support for the background colour --- really no need to make a mess by using it inside an argument.