# Rmarkdown: backticks are not formatting output as code when writing inline

Tags: formatting, latex, r-markdown, pdf-generation

How can I make a text appear like code in Rmarkdown output? Like this: `text formatted as code`?

Putting my text between backticks is not producing this effect (like it has done above). Instead text is being formated verbatim.

Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69438444/how-to-highlight-an-inline-code-snippet-in-latex/70658157#70658157

Comment: I saw that this uses another Latex package (listings). I noticed that when I knit to HTML instead of PDF the highlighting works fine. Does this mean that the highlighting with backticks does not work in a PDF output?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the backsticks are not working for pdf output (https://community.rstudio.com/t/highlighting-text-inline-in-rmarkdown-or-bookdown-pdf/35118/4).

I was able to solve this by using the `soul` and `xcolor` packages and by incluind the following line in my header:

```
\usepackage{soul, xcolor} 
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\sethlcolor{codegray}
```

Now I can use the tag `hl{text}` to produce the desired result. Although I still have to switch all my backticks by this tag in my document.

Comment: Using soul to highlight verbatim material is very ... brave. Use a package like listings or minted for this task, they are specifically made for this purpose!